# ng-hide animation for md-button not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have simple css animation effect:

```
.sample-show-hide {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 1.5s;
    transition:all linear 1.5s;
}

.sample-show-hide.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}

.sample-show-hide.ng-show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I tried to animate `md-button` with it. Animation is fine for showing, but on hidding there is no effect. When I changed to simple `<button>` tag, animation works for both show/hide. Is there way to fix it?

Comment: can you post your html too, would be good to see the problem on fiddle for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-hide` have property `transition: none`, use the following css

```
.sample-show-hide {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 1.5s  !important;
    transition:all linear 1.5s !important;
}
```

[check on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salalaslam/28hz3duq/)